# React Hook useState Not Updating UI

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React Hooks and I'm trying to update the quantity in a shopping cart using the following code;

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import cookie from "react-cookies";
import CheckoutItems from "./CheckoutItems";
import restHelper from "../../shared/RestHelper";

const Checkout = () => {
    const [cart, setCart] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const cartId = cookie.load("RbCartId");

        if (cartId){
            (async () => {
                const cart = await restHelper.getUserCart(cartId);
                setCart(cart);
            })();
            }
    }, []);

    const handleQtyUpdate = (evt, id) => {
        let _cart = cart;
        let items = _cart.cartItems.filter(x => x.id === id);
        let cartItem = { ...items[0] };
        cartItem.quantity = Number(evt.target.value);
        const index = _cart.cartItems.findIndex(x => x.id === cartItem.id);
        _cart.cartItems[index] = cartItem;
        setCart(_cart);
    };

    return (
        <section>
            <div className="container" style={{ marginTop: "80px" }}>
                <h3 className="rb-highlight">Shopping Cart</h3>
                <table className="table" style={{marginTop: "20px"}}>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Items</th>
                            <th style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>Price</th>
                            <th style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>Quantity</th>
                            <th style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>Total</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <CheckoutItems cart={cart} onQtyUpdate={handleQtyUpdate} />
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}
export default Checkout;
```

The CheckoutItems component is

```js
import React from "react";

function CheckoutItems({cart, onQtyUpdate}){
    if (!cart || cart.cartItems === 0){
        return <tr><td colSpan="4"><span className="rb-highlight">There are no items in your cart</span></td></tr>;
    }
    else{
        const cartItems = cart.cartItems.map((item, index) => {
            return <tr key={index}>
                <td>{item.description}</td>
                <td style={{textAlign: "right"}}>&euro;{item.cost}</td>
                <td style={{textAlign: "right"}}><input type="text" id={item.id} name="quantity" value={item.quantity} onChange={(evt) => onQtyUpdate(evt, item.id)} /></td>
                <td style={{textAlign: "right"}}>&euro;{item.cost * item.quantity}</td>
            </tr>
        })
        return cartItems;
    }
}

export default CheckoutItems;
```

The cart items are successfully updated in `handleQtyUpdate` however the value isn't updated in the UI.  From what I have read I should be using `useEffect` to update the cart but I'm not sure how to go about using it from `handleQtyUpdate`.

Comment: not hooks problem but existing object mutation (instead using new object) in state updating method .... would fail in `setState`, too

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The issue is state comparisons are shallow, meaning, in the case of an object only the reference will be compared.

In your example, you update the `cartItems` property but not the object instance, so as far as React is concerned the state hasn't changed because it won't check individual properties.

Try creating a completely new cart each time and you should see the UI update e.g.

```
 setCart({ ..._cart })
```

Comment: The cart is a single object with an array of items so the following worked;
`setCart(Object.assign({}, _cart))`

Comment: @Ray the spread operation in my example is the equivalent to `Object.assign`

Comment: My bad, I tried `[..._cart]` instead of `{..._cart}`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a copy of the object using spread operator

setCart({..._cart})