# Ant design Table as my UI does not update by react hooks

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using React Hooks, to asynchronous fetching  data from database and showing them with Ant Design Table. In my code, the dataSource  array (a state variable) does update, but Ant Design table does not. I realy need some help, Thanks.

I tried these answers, and unfortunately I could not solve my problem.

[The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

[React Hook useState Not Updating UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690934/react-hook-usestate-not-updating-ui)

my code is as follows:

```
const RequestList = ({ user }) => {
  const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function startFetching() {
      const { data: _dataSource } = await getRequests();
      setDataSource((dataSource) => [...dataSource, ..._dataSource]);
    }
    startFetching();
  }, []);
  
  // ...
  
  return <Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} />;
};

export default RequestList;
```

Comment: It's likely that you're getting an error thrown somewhere inside your `useEffect()`. One of the problems of this way of doing things is that it's very easy to lose errors because they just get thrown and never caught, and they might not even appear in console. Try adding some try/catch blocks in your function.

Comment: Another good technique for React applications is to wrap the whole thing in an error boundary, and then use an asynchronous hook like `useAsync` which will help you rethrow asynchronous errors.

Comment: please add how you configuring the columns and the structure of dataSource with your question.

Answer (score 0):

please try this way, wrapping with a condition:

```
return {dataSource && <Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} />}
```